# Rails render conditional partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following renders and I need them to be conditional parcials:

```
<%= render 'one' %>
<%= render 'two' %>
```

Is there anyway of making something like this work?

```
<%= render (if true ? 'one' : 'two' ) %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= render true ? 'one' : 'two' %>
```

or

```
<%= render 'one' if true %>
<%= render 'two' if false %>
```

or

```
<%= render true && 'one' || 'two' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

Not sure about that syntax but you can definitely do:

```
<% if true %>
   <%= render :partial => 'one' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => 'two' %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

just tried your preferred way and it works. Tertiary `if`s should be written the way @Arsen's answer is.